# MVC: How to mock after using HttpContextWrapper conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

```
Public Class PhotoUploadController

   Public ReadOnly Property IsMobileDevice As Boolean
       Get
          Return ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser.IsMobileDevice
       End Get
   End Property

   Function SavePhoto(model As PhotoUploadModel) As ActionResult
       If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Files(0).FileName) And IsMobileDevice Then
    Return View("Index", model)
   End If       
   End Function

End Class   

<TestMethod()>
 Public Sub SavePhoto_Test()

   Dim permissions As New List(Of String)
   permissions.Add(Constants.VIEW_ACCOUNTS)
   Dim mUser As New MockUser(ListOfPermissions:=permissions)
   Dim controller As PhotoUploadController = New PhotoUploadController(mUser, New PhotoRepository)
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current = New HttpContext(New HttpRequest("test", "http://www.yahoo.com/accounts", ""), New HttpResponse(New System.IO.StringWriter()))

   Dim browserMock = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of HttpBrowserCapabilities)()
   browserMock.Expect(Function(b) b.IsMobileDevice).Return(True)
   System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser = browserMock

   Dim currentContext As HttpContextBase = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of HttpContextWrapper)(System.Web.HttpContext.Current)
   currentContext.Expect(Function(fn) fn.Request.Files(0).FileName).Return("test.txt")
   'If I comment out the two lines above and uncomment the below line the IsMobile is set in the SavePhoto actionresult otherwise it is null.
   'Dim currentContext As HttpContextBase = New HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current)
   controller.ControllerContext = New ControllerContext(currentContext, New System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), controller)

   Dim model As New PhotoUploadModel(mUser)

   Dim result As ActionResult = controller.SavePhoto(model)

   Assert.IsNotNull(result)
   Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, GetType(ViewResult))

End Sub
```

Comment: As per the exception it is not a mock object. You need to create mock object. If you are ussing Rhino Mock you can use something line MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextWrapper>(); ?

Comment: New error ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser.IsMobileDevice is null when I call this object in my code. Why does the GenerateStub remove the browser information that I passed to the System.Web.HttpContext.Current? IF I remove the GenerateStub and add this Dim currentContext As HttpContextBase = New HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current). The ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser.IsMobileDevice has a value. Reason I added the browser mock code.

Comment: hi @user2868558, can you please provide/update your question with your complete Unit Test, and the system under test (of course omit any sensitive information). It is harder to give you a complete answer without seeing your code.

Comment: I took some of the code out.  For some reason the editor on here did not like a couple of items that I wrote.  So it does not look like code above.  I set the IsMobileDevice but I need to mock the context to add a filename.  For some reason I cannot do both.

Answer (score 1):

The below answer should guide you to the right direction.
*Note I'm not a VB.NET developer. Bear with me if my syntax aren't correct. I actually used a tool convert C# to VB :)*

First of there few issues with your Unit Test

a. You test method name is poorly written it does not reflect what's your *exact* intention is.

b. It is not easy to stub/set the expectation of

> ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser.IsMobileDevice

GetOverriddenBrowser is a static extension method. So it is not mockable.

c. Your Assert are verifying 2 things. First whether the result is null, and second the type of result is ViewResult. I would personally test the latter, which the type of result. If the result is not the test would throw an exception any way. By limiting to one assert you test method name become simpler to write.

To avoid the painfulness of stubbing out .IsMobileDevice I would simply simply introduce a property/more or less a Func/delegate property in your Controller. And I would set the IsMobileDevice in the constructor as below. This way I can simply stub value that return from IsMobileDeviceFunc in my Unit Test.

```
Imports System.Web.WebPages

Public Interface IUser
End Interface

Public Interface IPhotoRepository
End Interface

Public Class PhotoUploadModel
End Class

Public Class PhotoUploadController
    Inherits Controller

    Private m_IsMobileDeviceFunc As Func(Of Boolean)

    Public Sub New(user As IUser, repository As IPhotoRepository)
        IsMobileDeviceFunc = Function() 
        ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser().IsMobileDevice
    End Sub

    Public Property IsMobileDeviceFunc() As Func(Of Boolean)
        Get
            Return m_IsMobileDeviceFunc
        End Get
        Set(value As Func(Of Boolean))
           m_IsMobileDeviceFunc = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    Public Function SavePhoto(model As PhotoUploadModel) As ActionResult
       Dim isMobD = IsMobileDeviceFunc

       If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.Files(0).FileName) And isMobD() Then
           Return View("Index", model)
       End If

       Return New EmptyResult()
    End Function

End Class
```

**Unit Test**

```
 <TestMethod()> Public Sub SavePhoto_ActionExecute_ActionResultIsTypeOfViewResult()

    Dim sut = New PhotoUploadController(MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of IUser)(), MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of IPhotoRepository)())
    sut.IsMobileDeviceFunc = Function() True
    Dim currentContext = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of HttpContextBase)()
    Dim requestStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub(Of HttpRequestBase)()
    requestStub.Expect(Function(x) x.Files(0).FileName).[Return]("foo")
    currentContext.Expect(Function(x) x.Request).[Return](requestStub)
    sut.ControllerContext = New ControllerContext(currentContext, New RouteData(), sut)

    Dim result As ActionResult = sut.SavePhoto(New PhotoUploadModel())

    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, GetType(ViewResult))
 End Sub
```

[image]

Hope this would point you to the right direction.

Comment: In the constructor, ControllerContext.HttpContext.GetOverriddenBrowser.IsMobileDevice throws the NullReferenceException when I launch the website.

Comment: @user2868558 Thanks, there was minor syntax issues (not a VB expert), but I updated the solution with completely compiling code. You should not get the error. Please see the complete solution and a passing test.